# Handling exceptions produced by ParseTreeListener

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Newbie question. Imagine a `ParseTreeListener` implementation with dozens of enter- and exit- methods which require exception handling. To avoid coding try-catch for each of these 40+ methods individually, I'd prefer a solution which would allow to catch listener's exceptions in a centralized manner and still have a reference to the context (line, position) where the exception was thrown, just like in the imaginary code below:

```
TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
TestListener listener = new DefaultTestListener();
ParseTree tree = parser.entrynode();

try {
  walker.walk(listener, tree);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  LOG.info("Exception at " + tree.getContextWhereExceptionWasThrown());
}
```

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: Wouldn't that work as written? e would have the appropriate info. Of course this stops the tree walk. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy, no, it doesn't work this way, for example `parser.getCurrentToken()` (which I believed should work) returns the whole input string. I don't mind if the walk stops, I'd like to know where.

Comment: if getting the current token returns the entire input string, then somehow your lexer is matching the entire input string to a single token

Comment: this sounds strange as both my parser and listener are working just fine when no exceptions are thrown, the only guess here is that getCurrentToken() is not intended for such use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have only shown imaginary code, you need to verify the true source and kind of the Exceptions you are seeing.

Walking an otherwise valid parseTree should not throw any Exception other than those you choose to throw.  OTOH, the parser will throw exceptions of the type you seem to be concerned with.

If they are indeed parser exceptions, you can catch them explicitly as `RecognitionException` rather than `RuntimeException` exceptions.  That exception object has the methods you seem to be looking for: getContext, getOffendingToken, etc.

If they are instead occurring in the execution of the walker, you will need to clarify your question regarding the type of exception. If you are throwing the exception, include the relevant token indexes and intervals, obtained from the TerminalNodes and ParserRuleContext objects in the then current context, in a 'one size fits all' exception.

Comment: This is actually the question - is it possible to catch ANY RuntimeException thrown by the listener (let it be NPE) and being able to retrieve the context where it happened - the concept similar to Interceptors in Java EE.

Comment: If you are already executing in a container, then you have the called object and the underlying exception. If the exception occurred in the parse, cast the exception to a RecognitionException and call the methods on it. If the exception occurs in the walk, the called object will be the visitor or listener (both contain references to the current ParserRuleObject) or a method called from the visitor or listener. In any case, just reflect your way to the current ParserRuleContext.  If you are not in a container you will need to provide an AOP package on your own.